# Search Linked server name in sql server agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have around 4 servers(test1 , test2, test3, test4) and each server with 5 - 6 databases. Each server has around 60 SQL server agent jobs scheduled.

Each each job inside the servers has combination of sql statements and SSIS packages. Inside SQL statements, we have stored procs, which access tables from another servers.

Now i want to check whether server test2, is being used in sql server agent jobs of other servers.

i tried with the following query but not able to get any result

```
SELECT Job.name AS JobName, Job.enabled AS ActiveStatus, 
       JobStep.step_name AS JobStepName, JobStep.command AS JobCommand
FROM sysjobs Job INNER JOIN
     sysjobsteps JobStep
     ON Job.job_id = JobStep.job_id
 WHERE JobStep.command LIKE '%test2%'
```

but when i check manually in test1 server , i can see test2 server being used in stored procs and ssis packages.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Where the are the SSIS packages stored?  In the SQL Server or on the file system?  If the SQL Server, are there packages on each of the servers?

Comment: packages are stored in server as well as file system. Yes there are packages in all of the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  You will need to search the procedures, file system and SQL Server separately.  The job table only contains the entry point, not the definition for each step.

**SSIS Packages, stored in SQL Server**

SSIS packages are stored in the [msdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/msdb-database) table [sysssispackages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/sysssispackages-transact-sql).  The definition is stored in the column packagedata.  You'll need to cast the data, before you can read/search it.

```
-- How to read package data column.
SELECT TOP 10 
    [name],
    packagedata                                         AS [Before],
    CAST(CAST(packagedata AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML)    AS [After]
FROM
    sysssispackages
;
```

**SSIS Packages, stored on the file system**

These are XML text files.  You can search using your favorite method.  If you want to build your own solution [.Net has some great file handling ablities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Stored Procedures**

There are several methods, all of which return data from the system tables.  One approach is to use the [object definition function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql).

```
-- Returns definition of stored procedure.
SELECT
     OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'[Your-Schema].[Your-Procedure]'))
;
```

**If you want to bring this altogether**

Using the table [sysjobsteps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobsteps-transact-sql), you could build a package/app that searches for a given server name.  The final product would need to support all three search methods.  You might be able to use the subsystem column, to choose which search method should be used for each step.